# Google chrome on mobile overscroll stutters when border radius is on screen

Tags: html, css, reactjs, google-chrome, next.js

I've been having this weird lagging issue when scrolling to the bottom of the page on a website I'm working on  This only happens on chrome on Android from what I've tested. When I scroll to the bottom of the page, the "bounce" animation from the overscroll is very laggy and prevents me from scrolling back up for half a second. However, what I found was that this only happens if there is an element with a border radius in the viewport while the "bounce" animation is playing. Just simply removing the border radius fixes this issue. Another work around I found was setting "overscroll-bahavior" to none. Is there a solution to this where I can keep the default overscroll behavior but also keep the border radius? Is this a common issue? Can't really seem to find anything about it.

Here's a version of the website: https://advanced-car-creations.vercel.app/

The issue should be visible if you scroll quickly to the bottom of the page.